# Equivalent of reference 'Copy Local' in ASP.NET Web Site project

Tags: .net, asp.net

I don't see any exact duplicates in the Related Questions above, so here goes.  Please don't stone me if it is a duplicate.

Is there any way to achieve the same end as setting 'Copy Local' to True on a web application reference?  I could probably map a custom config section to the `<compilation><assemblies>` config section, and simple copy all assemblies to local, but that would be quite rude.  Should I be looking at tapping into a build provider or something?  I think the main issue here is identifying listed assemblies not normally present on the target platform, but this seems a very difficult task to me without simply using a hard-coded list, which will be out of date very quickly.

Comment: As far as I understood, Visual Studio did this for you, essentially setting everything to Copy Local, except assemblies in the .net framework. In saying that, a Build Provider would be the best way to achieve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the necessary references to copy in the post-build event perhaps?
or edit the .csproj file in any other way that would help achieve it.

For example you could have the copy section only happen during release builds.

Answer (score 1):

Any non GAC referenced assembly would be copied into the `bin` folder of the web application and be deployed with it (if using the deploy functionality of visual studio).

Do you need something over and above this?

---

**Update**

You can't directly deploy GACed assemblies using a web application.

If these assemblies are not in the GAC on the deployment target, you will need to copy the relevant assemblies from the GAC into your application `bin` folder and ensure the references point to the copy in the `bin` folder.

Comment: Yes, I need GAC referenced assemblies to be copied into the bin folder.

Comment: @ProfK - Are these assemblies third party or MS ones?

Comment: @Oded, in this case they are 3rd party, the DevExpress controls.

Comment: @ProfK - You need to ensure that you are legally allowed to redistribute them. See here: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument3189

Comment: @Oded, I appreciate your advice, but seeing as DexExpress is a development suite, not being able to distribute software I develop with it would have long ago caused the total downfall of their business.  DevExpress is only an example in this case anyway, my question is more general and applies equally even to my own libraries that I may reference from the GAC.

Comment: @ProfK - I am just saying that _not_ all DevExpress executables _are_ redistibutable. Many are, of course, but not all.

Comment: @Oded, thanks, and I appreciate your input, but which binaries are redistributable and which are not, is really outside the scope of my question.

Comment: @Oded, I have just read your edit.  That is the whole reason for my question.  If you set "Copy local" on a GAC reference, VS copies it to your bin folder.  That isn't available in a web site type project, and I want to emulate it in a web site project.

Comment: @ProfK - I understand that, however, I couldn't find anything online (or documented) that will do this _automatically_.