# Two different versions of System.Net.Http. Local vs DEV server

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have an Asp>Net Website project that targets .NET v4.0. I make use of System.Net.Http in the project and have brought it in via NuGet. On my development machine everything works fine, however, when I deploy to my DEV server the project blows up with this error.

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Looking in SO I came across [this posting from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431975/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-2-0-0-0-in-mvc4-web-ap) where one of the answers suggests changing the bindingRedirect value as shown below.

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
```

This fixes the project on DEV, but every time I redeploy the same fix has to be applied. It seems to me that I have two different versions of `System.Net.Http.dll`. One on my local machine and one on DEV. How do I go about moving the version of `System.Net.Http.dll` from my development machine over to the DEV machine during deployment?

NOTE: I have searched for the option to set "Copy Local" for System.Net.Http but there is no option to Show All Files in solution explorer. Perhaps this is a Website Project and not a Web Application?

Comment: Expand references node in project explorer and find `System.Net.Http.dll` and set `CopyLocal=true`.

Comment: There is no references node in solution explorer. I think this is because it is a web site project.

Comment: Well, WebSiteProject does not support that. There are some workaround, read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278452/equivalent-of-reference-copy-local-in-asp-net-web-site-project